# VBA code that changes zoom level based on text/object in sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, zoom

All,

I've been looking for VBA code that achieves the following:

1. Sets zoom to 80% for worksheets that contain a certain key word
2. Sets zoom to 60% for worksheets that contain a picture
3. Sets zoom to 85% for all other worksheets

Here is the code that I have been trying to manipulate to suit this particular challenge, with my non-code comments indicating what I'd like to change:

```
 Sub ZoomAll() 
   Dim ws As Worksheet  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    For Each ws *with a picture* In Worksheets 
        ws.Activate
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 60
    Next
    For Each ws *that contains X text* In Worksheets 
        ws.Activate
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    Next
    For Each ws *that contains Y text* In Worksheets 
        ws.Activate
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

For a certain deliverable at my job, the manager prefers certain sheets within an excel workbook to be at different zoom levels depending on what the sheet contains. I've been able to find VBA code that sets a uniform zoom across all sheets, but I am looking for help writing code that is a little more flexible and allows me to vary the zoom depending on what the sheet contains.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Do you need to figure out how to code the tests for each worksheet? (has an images, contains X text, contains T text) -- contains the text _where_ has a picture _where_? Could maybe the worksheet names be used instead?

Comment: Thanks for the response, @cybernetic.nomad, the worksheets with the picture are exactly that: a worksheet with a copy and pasted image of a Vizio file in them (Enhanced Metafile) which usually spans columns A-N and rows 1-40. For these worksheets, I would like the zoom to be set to 60 %. The worksheets with text "X," are all in A1, and the worsheets with text "Y" are in A1 as well. By using these characteristics of each worksheet, I am hoping to partition the workbook into three "types" of worksheet that all correspond to a different zoom level. 60 for picture, 85 for Y text, and 80 for x text